# how to map a non-entity result set coming from a NameStoredProcedure in JPA 2.1?

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa

I am calling a postgresql procedure using jpa 2.1 and would like to convert the result set to a non-entity class called StoreAndCategoryID containing two integer fields called: storeid, categoryid. These two fields are the ones returned from the procedure.

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
    name = "Category.func_getcategorybytextsearchid",
    procedureName = "func_getcategorybytextsearchid",    
    parameters = {@StoredProcedureParameter(name = "textsearchid", type = Integer.class,
                                            mode = javax.persistence.ParameterMode.IN ),
          @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "mycursor", type = void.class, 
                                    mode = ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR )}
)
```

the below code is the proc executed on Postgresql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_getcategorybytextsearchid(textsearchid integer )
  RETURNS refcursor  AS
$BODY$
declare mycursor refcursor ;
BEGIN
mycursor   = 'mycursor';

OPEN mycursor FOR (
            select storeid, categoryid 
            from item_full_text_search
            where itemfulltextsearchid = $1;

RETURN mycursor ;
end;
```

the below java code shows how I am calling the procedure

```
StoredProcedureQuery q = 
em.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("Category.func_getcategorybytextsearchid");
q.setParameter("textsearchid", textsearchid);

if (q.execute())
{
   //the result set needs to convert to StoreAndCategoryID class if possible.
   StoreAndCategoryID storeAndCategoryID  =  q.getOutputParameterValue("mycursor");  
}

public class StoreAndCategoryID
{
        int storeid;
        int categoryid;
}
```

how can I change @NamedStoredProcedureQuery to return/convert non-entity class StoreAndCategoryID?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can't map stored procedure result set to non entity class using `StoredProcedureQuery`.
But, if you'll use (if you can use JPQL query instead of stored procedure call) `TypedQuey` you can use [JPQL constructor expression](https://blogs.oracle.com/adf/ejb-dc-using-jpql-constructor-expressions)
or [@SqlResultSetMapping](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/SqlResultSetMapping.html) in `NativeQuery`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using @SqlResultSetMapping and  @ConstructorResult

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "CalendarsMapping", classes = {
    @ConstructorResult(targetClass = Calendar.class, columns = { @ColumnResult(name = "OutDate"),
            @ColumnResult(name = "CategoryID", type = Long.class), @ColumnResult(name = "CategoryName"),
            @ColumnResult(name = "DepositDate"), @ColumnResult(name = "EventDate"),
            @ColumnResult(name = "EventType"), @ColumnResult(name = "Status"),
            @ColumnResult(name = "Effective", type = String.class),
            @ColumnResult(name = "Indicator", type = String.class), @ColumnResult(name = "TermDate"),
            @ColumnResult(name = "TID"), @ColumnResult(name = "TName"), @ColumnResult(name = "Series"),
            @ColumnResult(name = "Symbol"), @ColumnResult(name = "TType", type = String.class) }) })



StoredProcedureQuery procedureQuery = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery(
            "GetDepAndTerm", "CalendarsMapping");
procedureQuery.getResultList();
```

Comment: I have followed this but still the runtime exception, Unknown Entity. Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi @GowthamiReddy did you get a solution?